# python ConfigParser read file doesn't exist

Tags: python, exception, configparser

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('test.ini')
```

This is how we read a configuration file in Python. But what if the 'test.ini' file doesn't exist? Why doesn't this method throw an exception?

How can I make it throw exception if the file doesn't exist?

Comment: A one-liner solution has been suggested in [python 3 configparser.read() does not raise an exception when given a non-existing file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46869892/5433628). (It's for one file only, but could easily be extended to multible files with an iterator.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.read):

> If none of the named files exist, the `ConfigParser` instance will
> contain an empty dataset.

If you want to raise an error in case any of the files is not found then you can try:

```
files = ['test1.ini', 'test2.ini']
dataset = config.read(files)
if len(dataset) != len(files):
    raise ValueError("Failed to open/find all config files")
```

Comment: Why `config.read('test.ini')` shouldn't that be `config.read(files)`?

Answer (score 32):

You could also explicitly open it as a file.

```
try:
    with open('test.ini') as f:
        config.read_file(f)
except IOError:
    raise MyError()
```

EDIT: Updated for python 3.

Comment: This worked. By the way: `readfp()` is obsolete now (at least in Python 3). It is now called `read_file()`.

Comment: Update Nov2019/python 3, beware/adapt accordingly:
DeprecationWarning: This method will be removed in future versions.  Use 'parser.read_file()' instead.