# python 3 configparser.read() does not raise an exception when given a non-existing file

Tags: python, configparser

When I attempt to read a non-existing file using configparser.read, I think it ought to raise an exception.  It doesn't.  It returns an empty list instead.  Obviously, I can test for an empty list and raise an exception.  It just seems to me to be more intuitive and safer if the configparser.read raised a FileNotFound exception.

```
jeffs@jeffs-laptop:~/nbmdt (blue-sky)*$ python3.6
Python 3.6.2 (default, Oct  2 2017, 16:51:32)  [GCC 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2)] on linux 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import configparser
 >>> config=configparser.ConfigParser()
 >>> config.read("xyzzy.xyz")
[]
 >>> config.read("nbmdt.ini")
 ['nbmdt.ini']
 >>>
```

Thank you

Comment: The docs explain that this is so you can look for a config file in several different places: https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.read. I guess they probably could throw an exception if nothing was found.

Comment: also doesn't throw exception when we don't have permissions to view the file's content ... and raise later in the code about "block not found"

Answer (score 10):

As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read) makes clear, you can pass any number of filenames to the `read` method, and it will silently ignore the ones that cannot be opened.

If you want to see an exception on failure to open the file, try the `read_file` method instead:

```
config.read_file(open("xyzzy.xyz", "r"))
```